# Why does a useCallback option have to be called with a class component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am stumped. I have been trying to get a simple cleartext button to work. I have tried all the option available on this platform but nothing is working for me.  React Hook `useCallback` cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook. I have no idea why this error is occurring. I am pretty new to react can anyone please help? I am trying to clear the text on a click of the clear button.

```js
import React, { Component, useCallback, useState  } from "react";


import {
  Button,
  Input,
  Footer,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardImage,
  CardTitle,
  CardText
} from "mdbreact";

import blankImg from "./blank.gif";

import "./style.css";
import "./flags.min.css";

import countriesList from "./countries.json";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

  renderCountry = country => {
    const { search } = this.state;
    var code = country.code.toLowerCase();

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
      e.target.value = '';
    }, []);
   
    return (
      <div className="col-md-3" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <p className="">
              <img
                src={blankImg}
                className={"flag flag-" + code}
                alt={country.name}
              />
            </p>
            <CardTitle title={country.name}>
              {country.name.substring(0, 15)}
              {country.name.length > 15 && "..."}
            </CardTitle>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  };

  onchange = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };
  
  

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    const filteredCountries = countriesList.filter(country => {
      return country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
   

    return (
      <div className="flyout">
        <main style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
             
              <div className="col">
                <Input
                  label="Search Country"
                  icon="search"
                  onChange={this.onchange}
                />
                <button onClick={handleClick}> Click to clear</button>
              </div>
              <div className="col" />
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              {filteredCountries.map(country => {
                return this.renderCountry(country);
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
        <Footer color="indigo">
          <p className="footer-copyright mb-0">
            &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} Copyright
          </p>
        </Footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: _"React Hook "useCallback" cannot be called in a class component"_ - Error message is prettry self-explanatory. You can't use hooks in class components.

Comment: Basically, what you have to do is to move the `renderCountry` outside the `App` class component and put it into its own functional component, if you want to use the React hooks you are using.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this other than react hooks? @secan

Comment: You don't need `useCallback` or something similar in class components.

Comment: Where is `e` declared? Considering the content of the function you can move it completely out of the class, as a standalone utility function. Then you don't get any issues with references, as it is always the same function. Wait a moment, shouldn't is be `handleClick = () => { this.setState({ search: ""}); }`

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the reply but when I setState " " for the search variable..the filtered options are getting reset back to displaying all previous ones..but I need the text inside the search box to get cleared. That is why I was passing the e value.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot useCallBack hook in class Component,we can do a simple thing to clear the button text, by using
a button text state, i.e. {  btnTxt: "Clear ButtonText"} than update the state onclick

```
import React, { Component, useCallback, useState  } from "react";


import {
  Button,
  Input,
  Footer,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardImage,
  CardTitle,
  CardText
} from "mdbreact";

import blankImg from "./blank.gif";

import "./style.css";
import "./flags.min.css";

import countriesList from "./countries.json";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    search: "",
    btnTxt: "Clear ButtonText"
  };

  renderCountry = country => {
    const { search } = this.state;
    var code = country.code.toLowerCase();

   
    return (
      <div className="col-md-3" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <p className="">
              <img
                src={blankImg}
                className={"flag flag-" + code}
                alt={country.name}
              />
            </p>
            <CardTitle title={country.name}>
              {country.name.substring(0, 15)}
              {country.name.length > 15 && "..."}
            </CardTitle>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  };

  onchange = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };
  
  

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    const filteredCountries = countriesList.filter(country => {
      return country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
   

    return (
      <div className="flyout">
        <main style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
             
              <div className="col">
                <Input
                  label="Search Country"
                  icon="search"
                  onChange={this.onchange}
                />
                <button onClick={()=>  this.setState({btnText:""})}> {this.state.btnTExt}</button>
              </div>
              <div className="col" />
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              {filteredCountries.map(country => {
                return this.renderCountry(country);
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
        <Footer color="indigo">
          <p className="footer-copyright mb-0">
            &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} Copyright
          </p>
        </Footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I would not say the `shouldComponentUpdate()` is the class equivalent of `useCallback()`; the first one is a life-cicle method and, as the name suggests, actually determine whether a component should be re-rendered or not. The `useCallback()` hook instead guarantees that a function is not re-defined every time the component re-renders but it does not determine in itself whether the component should re-render or not.

Comment: sorry about that, I got things little mixed . thanks for the clearance

Answer (score 1):

It is because you try to use hooks in a class based component. You can only use hooks like `useCallback` in functional components. Therefore you are mixing the concepts of object oriented and functional programming.

The following should do the trick:

```
import React, { Component, useCallback, useState  } from "react";


import {
  Button,
  Input,
  Footer,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardImage,
  CardTitle,
  CardText
} from "mdbreact";

import blankImg from "./blank.gif";

import "./style.css";
import "./flags.min.css";

import countriesList from "./countries.json";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ""
  };

   const handleClick = (e) => {
      e.target.value = '';
    };

  renderCountry = country => {
    const { search } = this.state;
    var code = country.code.toLowerCase();

    
   
    return (
      <div className="col-md-3" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
            <p className="">
              <img
                src={blankImg}
                className={"flag flag-" + code}
                alt={country.name}
              />
            </p>
            <CardTitle title={country.name}>
              {country.name.substring(0, 15)}
              {country.name.length > 15 && "..."}
            </CardTitle>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  };

  onchange = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };
  
  

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    const filteredCountries = countriesList.filter(country => {
      return country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
   

    return (
      <div className="flyout">
        <main style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }}>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
             
              <div className="col">
                <Input
                  label="Search Country"
                  icon="search"
                  onChange={this.onchange}
                />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Click to clear</button>
              </div>
              <div className="col" />
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              {filteredCountries.map(country => {
                return this.renderCountry(country);
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
        <Footer color="indigo">
          <p className="footer-copyright mb-0">
            &copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} Copyright
          </p>
        </Footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there's an error stating that const handleClick code is a syntax error...

Comment: Sorry! Try: ```const handleClick = (e) => {
      e.target.value = '';
    };```

Comment: I edited it in the answer above, you need to pass the event element as input to the Callback which processes it.

Answer (score 1):

`useCallback` hooks can only be used in functional components OR in a custom Hook **NOT** in class components.

You have declared your App component in class based approach i.e. Object oriented approach. To use `useCallback` hook for this, you should change your App component declaration to a functional component or Custom hook.

Something like this

```
function App() {
    return (
       <>Hello World!</>
    );
}
```